# DateTime instance has no attribute 'strptime' / Convert one DateTime format to Another

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, datetime-format

I have an API that returns all dates in the following format:

```
{
'date': {
'year': 2014L,
'month': 3L,
'day': 14L
},
'hour': 22L,
'minute': 59L,
'second': 0L,
'timeZoneID': 'Europe/Paris'
}
```

Which is considered to be DateTime Format. I first trying to use substrings to extract YYYY-MM-DD from it but it wouldn't work as it is not a string. I then tried using this:

```
unformatted_date.strptime('%y-%m-%d')
```

This returns the following error:

```
AttributeError: DateTime instance has no attribute 'strptime'
```

I also tried `datetime.datetime.strptime` and `strftime` but still didn't work. When I try searching for what functions I can use to convert DateTime format, I mainly get suggestions from string, or just general documentation on datetime but not DateTime. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone every runs into such a format, the solution to get the attribute is:

```
def format_my_date(unformatted_date):

date = unformatted_date.date

date_string = '{}-{}-{}'.format(
    date.year,
    "%02d" % date.month,
    "%02d" % date.day
)

return date_string
```